# Pandas DataFrame. Aggregate column in depends of values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate

There is an 'orders' dataframe with columns `driver_uuid, payment_type, order_price, bonus_payment`.
payment_type column has values like 'cash', 'card'. order_price is an integer. bonuses is an integer too.
[image]

I need to group orders by driver_uuid, and then for each payment type count the order_price sum and add those sums to separate columns. So I need the resulting df with columns like this:

```
[driver_uuid, cash_order_price_sum, card_order_price_sum, bonus_payment_sum]
```

cash_order_price_sum column contains the order_price sum for orders_ which have payment_type 'cash'.
card_order_price_sum is same, but for 'card' payment_type.
I am using groupby and agg functions witn NamedAgg.

```
grouped_orders = (
    orders.groupby('driver_uuid')
    .agg(
        cash_order_price_sum= here sum(real_price) if payment_type == 'cash',
        card_order_price_sum= here sum(real_price) if payment_type == 'card',
        bonus_payment_sum=pandas.NamedAgg('bonus_payment', 'sum')
    )
)
```

Is it possible to do it this or another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace not matched rows to missing values in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then pass helper columns to `agg`:

```
grouped_orders = (
    orders
    .assign(cash = orders['order_price'].where(orders['payment_type'] == 'cash'),
            card = orders['order_price'].where(orders['payment_type'] == 'card'))
    .groupby('driver_uuid')
    .agg(
        cash_order_price_sum=('cash', 'sum'),
        card_order_price_sum=('card', 'sum'),
        bonus_payment_sum=('bonus_payment', 'sum')
    )
)
```

Comment: I think `"real_price"` should be `"order_price"`